# MySQL TCP Connection

Tags: mysql, connection, tcp, mysql-error-1130

I have a MySQL Database which I want to connect to from a different computer, preferably using TCP/IP. What is the easiest way to do this. Currently I have tried just putting the IP address of the computer in, and it comes up with Error #1130, which is no help.

Any nice easy ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "skip-networking" is not in your my.cnf file (restart MySQL if it is after changing it), and that you've created a user with permissions to connection from your remote host.  Something like:

GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON mydb.mytable TO "myuser"@"myotherhost" IDENTIFIED BY "somepassword";

Comment: I have done this, but I now get the error message "Could not connect to the specified instance. MySQL Error Number 2003 Can't connect to MySQL server on '*IPADDRESS*' (10061) If you want to check the network connection, please click the ping button" I can ping off the server, but not connect.

Comment: Ensure that you don't have a firewall in the way, and that your MySQL server resolves the IP of your client to the same hostname you entered as 'myotherhost' in the query above.  If your DNS has changed recently, you might need to issue a 'flush hosts' to clear the hosts cache, and for sure will need to issue a 'flush permissions' to clear the access control cache.